# UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewLayOut

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to have the content in a uicollectionviewcell grow bigger when it scroll moving in one direction. i initially set the size of the cell to the largest size i want, then the content inside the cell is half in terms of the size. the content is an uiimageview.

So I have a custom **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** in which I subclassed the ***layoutAttributesForElementsInRect*** to make the uiimageview in the cells grow bigger when it is moving in one direction. i also have ***shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange*** to return YES
Everything works perfectly  when i scroll, the imageview will grow larger. However if i select a cell to push to a new viewcontroller, and then when i click the back button to come back to this uicolletionview, the enlarged uiimageview in severals cells are showing in the original size. They can only go back to the correct enlarged size if i scroll again, why is that? and how can i make it keep its enlarged size after getting pushed?

i tried invalidatelayout but it will just refresh the layoutattributes with correct enlarged size of the content, but the view is just not updated eventhough the size is already enlarged.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when designing cv cells and would gess the issue is with when the subviews get calls to update their size, which might not happen when the view refreshes.

Instead of resizing content in the cell, you might want to dynamically size the cells themselves and have the content automatically adjust to that size. Calling [mycollection invalidateLayout] then should be all you need, maybe not even that.

The method is 
**collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:**
which you declare in your **UICollectionViewFlowLayout.h**

If you then run into trouble where subviews do not resize with cell size, related problems can arise from constraints/autolayout etc of the subviews.